# Webrequest proxy

Tags: c#, proxy

Постоянно выбивается ошибка:

> $exception  {"Удаленный сервер возвратил ошибку: (429) Unknown."}

Подумал что идёт много запросов, и меня не пускает, решил подключить прокси, и менять их когда такая ошибка. Посмотрите, мб что то не так?

```
Uri sites = new Uri(url);
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sites);
WebProxy myproxy = new WebProxy(MyProxyHostString, MyProxyPort);
req.Proxy = myproxy;
req.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
req.CookieContainer = GetUriCookieContainer(sites);

HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
```

Comment: Код работоспособный. дело в прокси или в удаленном хосте. Уверены что у вас именно HTTP прокси? и они точно рабочие?

Comment: Возможно, дело в сайте http://stackoverflow.com/a/24323342